# Table name in Firebird has a lot of extra space

Tags: sql, firebird

So, I created a table in Firebird, using Python fdb library like so:

```
>>> import fdb

>>> conn = fdb.connect(...)
>>> sql = "CREATE TABLE test_table(id integer not null)"
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute(sql)
>>> conn.commit()
```

However, when I list tables, I get this strange result:

```
>>> tables = []
>>> sql = "select rdb$relation_name from rdb$relations 
       where rdb$view_blr is null and (rdb$system_flag is null or rdb$system_flag = 0)"
>>> cursor.execute(sql)
>>> res = cursor.fetchall()
        for r in res:
            tables.append(r[0])
>>> tables
['TEST_TABLE                     ']
```

What the heck is going on? Where does this stupid extra space come from? Why my table is named `"TEST_TABLE            "` and not just `"TEST_TABLE"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Field:

```
RDB$RELATION_NAME is CHAR(31)
```

CHAR is padded with spaces.

> The most important difference is that CHAR is padded with spaces and
> VARCHAR is not. For example, if you have:
>
> CREATE TABLE t1 ( c1 VARCHAR(2), c2 CHAR(2) );
>
> INSERT INTO t1 (c1,c2) VALUES ('a', 'a');
>
> The column c1 will contain value 'a', while column c2 will contain
> value 'a ' with additional space.
> Trailing spaces are ignored when doing comparisons, so both columns would >match the
>
> WHERE c = 'a'
>
> clause of some query. Trailing spaces are respected by LIKE operator, which >is a source of confusion for beginners

See : http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq237/

Comment: It is one of those nasty things that you encounter in one database among dozens. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that this padding, and the somewhat unexpected behavior that trailing spaces are ignored for `CHAR` equality comparisons, is mandated by standard SQL.  Firebird users are well acquainted with the [`TRIM()`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-trim.html) function.

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if the metadata tables would use varchar instead, but legacy and all that...